# Can't run gwt hello world on Netbeans 7

Tags: gwt, netbeans-7

Good day! I have begun with gwt 2.5. I have installed org-netbeans-modules-gwt4nb-2.10.5.nbm on NetBeans_7. After I built and ran an easy gwt app([enter link description here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-gwt.html)) in NetBeans_7 using GlassFish 3+, default browser (firefox_14) started up a corresponding page and output the empty one. What's the problem? Also I installed the gwt dev plug-in on firefox_14 but I have been getting the same result.
Main Entry Point

```
...
public class MainEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of MainEntryPoint
     */
    public MainEntryPoint() {
    }

    /**
     * The entry point method, called automatically by loading a module that
     * declares an implementing class as an entry-point
     */
    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final Label label = new Label("Hello, GWT!!!");
        final Button button = new Button("Click me!");

        button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                label.setVisible(!label.isVisible());
            }
        });

        RootPanel.get().add(button);
        RootPanel.get().add(label);
    }
}
...
```

HelloGWT.html

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the browser's rendering engine into
"Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration with a "Quirks Mode" doctype may
lead to some differences in layout.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name='gwt:module' content='gwt.intro.Main=gwt.intro.Main'>
        <title>Main</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="gwt.intro.Main/gwt.intro.Main.nocache.js"></script>
    <!-- RECOMMENDED if your web app will not function without JavaScript enabled -->
    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I receive the following warnings:

1. GWT Compiling client-side code.
   **WARNING**: 'com.google.gwt.dev.GWTCompiler' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
   Use 'com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler' instead.
   (To disable this warning, pass -Dgwt.nowarn.legacy.tools as a JVM arg.);
2. Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter'
     Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
        Checking rule 
           **[WARN]** Detected warnings related to 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver'.   Are validation-api-.jar and validation-api--sources.jar on the classpath?
           Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
           **[WARN]** Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule

As soon as I run the app, I get the following message from server: http://postimage.org/image/uf6lcczjb/

Comment: What is your app doing? Can you show us the EntryPoint class? Make sure to add something to the RootPanel.

Comment: Yes. I call the RootPanel with no parameter (so, this one wraps the <body> element) and add a label and a button to the panel: http://pastie.org/4376291

Comment: The EntryPoint class and your host page do look fine to me. Did you check if there are any errors during compilation or while starting up dev mode? Dev mode should give you a 'Module loaded' message if everything worked as expected.

Comment: I have edited my message and have pointed out all the warnings, that I receive from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The GWT4NB plugin seems to use the old GWT compiler class, that is why you get the warnings. However that should not be a problem. The 404 error suggest that there is something missing or you point the browser to the wrong URL. The name of your host page must match the name of the page in the URL. Since your host page is called *HelloGWT.html*, make sure the URL you open looks something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloGWT.html
```

For the final build I suggest you use Ant or Maven. Check out the official GWT documentation [Compile and run in production mode](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/gettingstarted#compile) and [Deploy a GWT Application](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying).

Answer (score 1):

Open the gwt.properties file and change the gwt.output.dir entry as needed (/ followed with the value of the entry gwt.module).
Meziano